# How to add new line while sharing text in WinRt

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, share, email-client, charms-bar

I want to share some text using mail client on windows 8, in which I want to display new lines. It displays it correctly in notepad on using `\r\n` but doesn't work with the `SetText` function in `DataTransferManager`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to set text in HTML and not send it as string.

Suppose the text you want to share is in `string textToShare;`
Note that you will be sending a string in HTML, so you need to replace all new line characters with `<br/>`

instead of

```
theRequest.Data.SetText(textToShare);
```

use

```
theRequest.Data.SetHtmlFormat(HtmlFormatHelper.CreateHtmlFormat(textToShare));
```